# create facebook event from my website

Tags: facebook, events

I need to create an event on Facebook directly from my website.
I downloaded facebook SDK v4, I created the connection to my facebook application, now how can I create the event?
I tried several guides but refer to the older versions of the SDK.

now in Graph API -> reference -> event is written:

Publishing

You can not create events via the Graph API.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message should be clear enough, it is not possible to create events with the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/event#publish

This change happened with v2.0 of the API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

Comment: there is no other way to create then?

Comment: how does eventbrite still do it then?

Comment: they either have a special deal with facebook, or they do something that is not allowed, or they don´t do it at all ;)

Comment: Just tested and they can still do it